# Why does passing a variable as an argument works sporadically where passing div tag work every time?

Tags: jquery

I have a file test.js

at the top of test.js I have the following variable declared:

```
var requiredDiv = $("<span class='markrequired'>*</span>");
```

I then have a function that loops through a class and prepends the above variable/div to a div

```
$("#dvMain :input:not([type=hidden]):not([type=submit]):not([type=button])").closest(".form-group").prepend(requiredDiv);
```

while this works 99% of the time, there will be random instances of textboxes where the icon does NOT appear

however, if I change the code to this:

```
$("#dvMain :input:not([type=hidden]):not([type=submit]):not([type=button])").closest(".form-group").prepend($("<span class='markrequired'>*</span>"));
```

it appears everywhere it is supposed to.  Why does one always work and not the other?

Comment: I've tested and both work as expected, all the time. The issue must lie somewhere else in your code. Maybe some other JS or the HTML?

Comment: @CarlMarkham guessing you tested it wrong if the first method worked as OP wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are appending the same element each time and not a new one. That means it takes the element from where it was and moves it to the new location.

If you are using the same base element as a template, than you need to make a copy of it. It is easy to do with jQuery's clone method.

```
...closest(".form-group").prepend(requiredDiv.clone());
```

Example Showing non clone vs clone:

```js
var elem1 = $("<span>Hello 1</span>");
var elem2 = $("<span>Hello 2</span>");


$("#out1").append(elem1);
$("#out1").append(elem1);

$("#out2").append(elem2.clone());
$("#out2").append(elem2.clone());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="out1"></div>
<div id="out2"></div>
```